# Hardening PHP forums

Tags: php, javascript, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
>   [Preventing XSS with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255343/preventing-xss-with-php)

I own a database with old php forums, and I have a textarea that I want to harden from the XSS.. I am new in that field..

The textarea is defined as :

```
 <textarea name="information" cols="60" row="4" id="infoid" > < /textarea>
```

What should I add to prevent it from taking " < , >"  symbols ???

Comment: what do u mean ?? I am totally new

Comment: Google what zerk just told you.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: It's surprising that you are aware of xss but have never heard about `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: I found this <?php 
function htmlspanishchars($str) 
{ 
    return str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8")); 
} 
?> When I add it to the code it will work, I dont add any thing to the textarea tag ??

Comment: asprin, I just started learning

Comment: how about just googling htmlspecialchars as Daedalus told you? alternately i will now go against the law and give you the first search result (querying my brain) http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Many of your questions are getting closed! Beware! a multitude of closed and downvoted questions will get you **automatically banned by the system**! Shape up!

Answer (score 0):

Why not take anything that comes your way? Convert and escape those characters. i.e `<` is converted to `&lt;` etc. That will keep the punters happy AKA the people paying the cash.

Also it is trivial see [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: emm can some one use $lt in reverse to hack me ?? !!!!

Comment: Also, where should I add this function string htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )

Comment: Start with php's manual, @user1413188.

Comment: No.  I mean google 'php manual' and start reading, @user1413188.